# Catalog Product Image on top of text

Tags: catalog, product-images

My product images are displaying on top of the text. I've been hours trying to solve this but my knowledge is not great. I've uploaded View.phtml below, if there is anything else i should upload to help someone solve this problem please tell me. Thanks!

[THE PROBLEM](http://corkandbarrelstore.com/mywines/wines/umbral-chardonnay.html)

[View.phtml](http://puu.sh/kBXni/a60b12a200.txt)

Comment: Please add a screenshot to point out what you mean

Comment: I could not add more than 2 links, but the problem was  the image overlaping with the text on the page i linked as "the problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css file line number 1455.

```
http://corkandbarrelstore.com/skin/frontend/default/theme629/css/styles.css
```

in class `.product-view .product-img-box` remove `text-align:center` and your issue will be fix.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, its solved, i still have a little problem with the border but what i asked was solved. Thanks a lot again :)